# Slider image id

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a small problem with a small jQuery script that my slide images. The script itself works very well, its purpose being to scroll through the images indeed "fade", a classic.

The problem is that if I want to use it for another block on the page, well it no longer works properly .. The problem is certainly located at the id, but can not make it work.

Here is the script:

```
function slider() {

    function animate_slider(){
        $('.slider #'+shown).animate({
            opacity:0 // fade out
        },1000);
        $('.slider #'+next_slide).animate({
            opacity:1.0 // fade in
        },1000);
        //console.log(shown, next_slide);
        shown = next_slide;
    }

    function choose_next() {
        next_slide = (shown == sc)? 1:shown+1;
        animate_slider();
    }

    $('.slider #1').css({opacity:1}); //show 1st image
    var shown = 1;
    var next_slide;
    var sc = $('.slider img').length; // total images
    var iv = setInterval(choose_next,3500);
    $('.slider_nav').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(iv); // stop animation
    }, function() {
        iv = setInterval(choose_next,3500); // resume animation
    });
    $('.slider_nav span').click(function(e){
        var n = e.target.getAttribute('class');
        //console.log(e.target.outerHTML, n);
        if (n=='prev') {
            next_slide = (shown == 1)? sc:shown-1;
        } else if(n=='next') {
            next_slide = (shown == sc)? 1:shown+1;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        animate_slider();
    });
}

window.onload = slider;
```

Any idea ? Thank you all :)

Comment: Could you provide your html structure? Am i right if i think that your ID's are numbers (and it is not proper, of course)?

Comment: `$('.slider')` will target all attributes with that class. If you have two code blocks this one piece of code will affect both... which is not what you want. You would be better off writing this as a jQuery plugin where the element is the one you choose in the jQuery selector the plugin targets, not hard coded into your logic.

Comment: Hi guys ! I've upload my code on http://jsfiddle.net/AzGAH/1/ (but don't work, it's fast, just for see html code)

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure of what u want to do, but if you want reusibality :

**EDIT :** i ve modified assuming that your 2 slides are independant

this is a quick solution, as mentioned  @David Barker, it would be more clean to do a jQuery plugin

**JS :**

```
var sliderTop = "#slider.top";  
var sliderBottom = "#slider.bottom";


 function slider(el) {

    function animate_slider(el){
        $(el + shown).animate({
            opacity:0 // fade out
        },1000);
        $(el + next_slide).animate({
            opacity:1.0 // fade in
        },1000);
        //console.log(shown, next_slide);
        shown = next_slide;
    }

    function choose_next(el) {
        next_slide = (shown == sc)? 1:shown+1;
        animate_slider(e);
    }

    $(el + ' #1').css({opacity:1}); //show 1st image
    var shown = 1;
    var next_slide;
    var sc = $(el + ' img').length; // total images
    var iv = setInterval(choose_next,3500);
    $(el + '_nav').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(iv); // stop animation
    }, function() {
        iv = setInterval(choose_next,3500); // resume animation
    });
    $(el + '_nav span').click(function(e){
        var n = e.target.getAttribute('class');
        //console.log(e.target.outerHTML, n);
        if (n=='prev') {
            next_slide = (shown == 1)? sc:shown-1;
        } else if(n=='next') {
            next_slide = (shown == sc)? 1:shown+1;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        animate_slider(el);
    });
}
window.onload = function() {
    slider(sliderTop);
    slider(sliderBottom);
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="slider" class="top">
    <h2>Nos partenaires</h2>
    <img id="1" src="" alt="">
    <img id="2" src="" alt="">
    <img id="3" src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="slider_nav">
    <span class="prev">Précédent</span><!--
    --><span class="next">Suivant</span>
</div>

<div id="slider" class="bottom">
    <h2>Nos partenaires</h2>
    <img id="1" src="" alt="">
    <img id="2" src="" alt="">
    <img id="3" src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="slider_nav">
    <span class="prev">Précédent</span><!--
    --><span class="next">Suivant</span>
</div>
```